# Sorting array with multiple column in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, webmethod

C# code

Method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static SubjectList[] GetStudentList(string location, string program, long batch, string term,string code ,string name)
{
    using (Entities obj = new Entities())
    {
        SubjectListStatus subObjStatus = new SubjectListStatus();
        List<string> rollno = obj.Student_Master.Where(i =>i.Student_Location==location && i.Student_Course==program && i.Student_Batch==batch).Select(i => i.Student_RollNo).ToList();
        foreach (var rollObj in rollno)
        {
            var listLoc = obj.Marks_Master.Where(k => k.Location == location && k.Course_ID == program && k.Subject_ID == code && k.Term_ID == term && k.Student_ID.Equals(rollObj)).ToList();
            foreach (var tempobj in listLoc)
            {
                SubjectList subObj = new SubjectList();
                subObj.Subject_Code = tempobj.Student_ID;                   
                subObj.Total_Obtained = tempobj.Marks_Obtained; ;
                subObj.Total_Outoff = tempobj.Marks_Total; ;
                subObjStatus.Add(subObj);
            }
        }
       //sort Here
        return subObjStatus.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class SubjectList
{
    public string Subject_Code { get; set; }
    public string Subject_Name { get; set; }      
    public long Total_Obtained { get; set; }
    public long Total_Outoff { get; set; }  
}
public class SubjectListStatus : List<SubjectList>
{
    public void Add(SubjectList st)
    {
        base.Add(st);
    }

}
```

I want to sort in descending order for column `Total_Obtained` before return data
I tried `Array.Sort` but shows following error

[image]

1) how to use `Array.Sort`

2) for that any other easy way to do such sorting

I put image for data 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use LINQ OrderBy and ToArray afterwards?

Comment: I want to sort on Total_Obtained which is part of Marks_Master table I tried like .OrderByDescending(i => i.Marks_Obtained)  but not works

Comment: I can't find where are you using that sort

Comment: before return data see I put comment like  //sort Here

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy, like all LINQ extension method don't modify the object, it only return a sequence which you need to store (or just return them directly). So in your code,

```
 return subObjStatus.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Total_Obtained).ToArray();
```

should work. In addition, I have several suggestions :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    //change to IEnumerable instead of array
    public static IEnumerable<SubjectList> GetStudentList(string location, string program, long batch, string term,string code ,string name)
{
    using (Entities obj = new Entities())
    {
        //If all subObjStatus did is keeping the SubjectList, you don't really need it
        //SubjectListStatus subObjStatus = new SubjectListStatus();
        //Don't store it into list, just keep it lazy loaded
        var rollno = obj.Student_Master.Where(i =>i.Student_Location==location && i.Student_Course==program && i.Student_Batch==batch).Select(i => i.Student_RollNo);
        foreach (var rollObj in rollno)
        {
            //same thing here, keep it lazy loaded
            var listLoc = obj.Marks_Master.Where(k => k.Location == location && k.Course_ID == program && k.Subject_ID == code && k.Term_ID == term && k.Student_ID.Equals(rollObj));
            foreach (var tempobj in listLoc)
            {
                SubjectList subObj = new SubjectList();
                subObj.Subject_Code = tempobj.Student_ID;                   
                subObj.Total_Obtained = tempobj.Marks_Obtained; ;
                subObj.Total_Outoff = tempobj.Marks_Total;
                subObj.Subject_Name = //you probably want the name too 
                yield return subObj;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Read more about [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) if you're not familiar.

The caller of GetStudentList can then just enumerate the result, or call ToArray if you really need it as Array.

Comment: thanks your code help me to reduce my code now it just few line but sorting work on puting  rollno.Contains(k.Student_ID) instead of foreach

Answer (score 0):

At the type of your sorting the `subObjStatus` is still of the `SubjectListStatus` type, if you insist on doing it that way you could do something like

```
return Array.Sort(subObjStatus.ToArray());
```

That way your `SubjectList` would have to implement the `IComparable` interface. Or you could use:

```
return Array.Sort(subObjStatus.ToArray(),//Custom IComparer);
```

For further reference you could check

[Array.Sort Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx)

Else you could do it with LINQ like:

```
subObjStatus.OrderBy(x => x.[variableToSort]);
```

And then the return. Which I believe is the better way.

Comment: I tried see image in question but get conversion error using delegate and second way donot get any error but sorting not work

Comment: And about the image I can't see the properties of the items so I don't understand the sorting

Comment: thanks for reply I got some different solution instead of using foreach i used rollno.Contains(k.Student_ID)  in where and then used .OrderByDescending(i => i.Marks_Obtained)  thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static SubjectList[] GetStudentList(string location, string program, long batch, string term,string code ,string name)
{
    using (Entities obj = new Entities())
    {
        SubjectListStatus subObjStatus = new SubjectListStatus();
        List<string> rollno = obj.Student_Master.Where(i =>i.Student_Location==location && i.Student_Course==program && i.Student_Batch==batch).Select(i => i.Student_RollNo).ToList();
        foreach (var rollObj in rollno)
        {
            var listLoc = obj.Marks_Master.Where(k => k.Location == location && k.Course_ID == program && k.Subject_ID == code && k.Term_ID == term && k.Student_ID.Equals(rollObj)).ToList();
            foreach (var tempobj in listLoc)
            {
                SubjectList subObj = new SubjectList();
                subObj.Subject_Code = tempobj.Student_ID;                   
                subObj.Total_Obtained = tempobj.Marks_Obtained; ;
                subObj.Total_Outoff = tempobj.Marks_Total; ;
                subObjStatus.Add(subObj);
            }
        }
        //return subObjStatus.ToArray();
    // use the below statement to sort by total_obtained in the descending order
       return subObjStatus.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Total_Obtained).ToArray();
    }
}
```